# How to delete old images from uploads folder after inserting insert a new image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am able to overwrite the image in the database but the old images still remains in the assets folder.
How can I delete the previous image from the assests folder when i insert a new one?

Please explain in a bit of details since i am a beginner.

```
public function image_insert(){

        $id=1;

        if ($this->input->post('submit') && !empty($_FILES['body_image']['name'])) {

            $body_image = $_FILES['body_image']['name'];
            if($body_image != NULL){
                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/image/';
                $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = '0'; // 0 = no file size limit
                $config['overwrite'] = true;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->do_upload('body_image');
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $body_image = $upload_data['file_name'];

            }




            $this->Home_model->insert_image($body_image,$id);
            redirect(base_url('landing_page/home_edit'));
        }


        else {
            redirect(base_url('landing_page/home_edit'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are storing image_path and name in DB, you can, after new upload, delete old file with unlink('full_file_name');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete a file which already exists in your image folder.
**Suppose your image folder path is: /assets/image/**

Then, the image delete code will be something like this.

```
$filePath="/assets/image/";
$fileName=$filePath."dummy.jpg";

if (file_exists($fileName)) 
{
     unlink($fileName);
}
```

The above code will call you before uploading the image in upload folder.

Comment: how can i delete the old image if i dont have its filename. Because when i upload a new image, its name will be overwritten in the database. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: you can write image delete code before the your code something like:

$this->Home_model->insert_image($body_image,$id);

redirect(base_url('landing_page/home_edit'));

Comment: @KallolMedhi If the answer given above is useful to you, then validate it help others too.

Answer (score 1):

you may use [File helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) to delete file :-

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$path='./assets/image/'.$file_name;
delete_files($path);
```